# Ctypes not finding symbols in shared library created using CMake

Tags: c++, python, c, cmake, ctypes

My CMake setting to create a shared lib in linux is something like

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC")

SET (LIB_UTILS_SRC
    Utils.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY (UTILS SHARED
    ${LIB_UTILS_SRC}
)
```

Source Utils.cpp

```
double addTwoNumber(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

When trying to access 'addTwoNumber' function using CTypes like

```
import os
import ctypes as c

libPath = '/home/AP/workspace/LearningCPP/lib/libUTILS.so'
libUTILS = c.cdll.LoadLibrary(libPath)

prototype = c.CFUNCTYPE(    
    c.c_double,                
    c.c_double,                
    c.c_double                
)
addTwoNumber = prototype(('addTwoNumber', libUTILS))

res = addTwoNumber(c.c_double(2.3), c.c_double(3.5) )
```

I am getting some message like.

```
AttributeError: /home/AP/workspace/LearningCPP/lib/libUTILS.so:
undefined symbol: addTwoNumber
```

I checked the libUTILS.so using the "nm --demangle libUTILS.so" command and it clearly shows the 'addTwoNumber' symbol in it.

Why am I still getting the "undefined symbol" message from python ?
I am guessing there must be some compiler flags to be set so that symbols are mangle properly. Any suggestion would be appreciated !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interesting, I usually use `numpy.ctypes` since I constantly have to deal with large data sets, and never had any issues but I think I know whats going on here, it's that the names are being mangled by the g++ compiler, I made it work this way:

Makefile:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -c Utils.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl -o libUTILS.so Utils.o
```

Utils.cpp

```
extern "C" double addTwoNumber(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

test.py

```
import os
import ctypes as c

libUTILS = c.cdll.LoadLibrary('libUTILS.so')

prototype = c.CFUNCTYPE(    
    c.c_double,                
    c.c_double,                
    c.c_double                
)
addTwoNumber = prototype(('addTwoNumber', libUTILS))

res = addTwoNumber(c.c_double(2.3), c.c_double(3.5) )
print res
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
5.8
```

note the `extern` keyword this makes sure the compiler doesn't mangle the name, you have to do some extra stuff when under windows, I did find http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/dllforpyinc.php which was kind of interesting.

I hope this helps.

my machine:

> $ g++ --version
>   i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> $ uname -a
>   Darwin MacBookPro 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was facing the same problem - turns out I simply needed to `extern "C"` all of my functions (as is also mentioned in the Python documentation in the [Extending Python with C or C++ section](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#writing-extensions-in-c)).